# Flask - Bad Request. Request file

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to do a file upload & enter data task into my SQLAlchemy using flask but I had this error when I filled my form & upload the file.
So, I found problem. It is "book = request.files['book']". But I can't solve this problem. Help me plz!!!

My HTML code:

```html
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input name="title" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title"><br>
        <input name="file" type="file" class="text-info">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Send">
</form>
```

My python code:

```html
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///books.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.secret_key = 'key'


class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    book = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Article %r' % self.id


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect(url_for('home'))


@app.route('/home', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.form['title']
        book = request.files['book']
        print('hello')
        article = Article(title=title, book=book.read())
        try:
            db.session.add(article)
            db.session.commit()
            return book.filename
        except:
            return "HI"
    else:
        return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/posts')
def post():
    article = Article.query.order_by(Article.id).all()
    return render_template("posts.html", article=article)


@app.route('/posts/<int:id>/del')
def post_del(id):
    article = Article.query.get_or_404(id)
    try:
        db.session.delete(article)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/posts')
    except:
        return "HI"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: Will you care to share error message also to pinpoint problem.

Comment: Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.